# Why does awk not filter the first column in the first line of my files?

Tags: awk

I've got a file with following records:

```
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_15102018.txt;1;CAB001
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_20102018.txt;2;CLI001
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_20102018.txt;32;CLI001
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_25102018.txt;1;CAB001
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_50102018.txt;1;CAB001
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_65102018.txt;1;CAB001
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_80102018.txt;2;CLI001
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_93102018.txt;2;CLI001
```

When I execute following oneliner awk:

```
cat lignes_en_erreur.txt | awk 'FS=";"{ if(NR==1){print $1}}END {}'
```

the output is not the expected:

```
 depots/import/HDN1YYAA_15102018.txt;1;CAB001
```

While I am suppose get only the frist column:

If I run it through all the records:

```
cat lignes_en_erreur.txt | awk 'FS=";"{ if(NR>0){print $1}}END {}'
```

then it will start filtering only after the second line and I get the following output:

```
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_15102018.txt;1;CAB001
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_20102018.txt
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_20102018.txt
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_25102018.txt
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_50102018.txt
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_65102018.txt
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_80102018.txt
depots/import/HDN1YYAA_93102018.txt
```

Does anybody knows why awk is skiping the first line only.
I tried deleting first record but the behaviour is the same, it will skip the first line.

Comment: If you want to print the first column only use `awk -F':' '{print $1}'`

Comment: You should set the field separator in the `BEGIN` block or with `-F` before the script.

Answer (score 5):

First, it should be

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"}{ if(NR==1){print $1}}END {}' filename
```

You can omit the END block if it is empty:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"}{ if(NR==1){print $1}}' filename
```

You can use the `-F` command line argument to set the field delimiter:

```
awk -F';' '{if(NR==1){print $1}}' filename
```

Furthermore, awk programs consist of a sequence of `CONDITION [{ACTIONS}]` elements, you can omit the `if`:

```
awk -F';' 'NR==1 {print $1}' filename
```

Comment: You miss the last option: `awk '(NR==1){print $1}' FS=; filename`

Comment: My intention was not to list "all" options. I just simplified the OPs script after fixing the original problem. I don't see an advantage in using the `FS=;` in favour of `-F';'`. Besides that, `(NR==1)` should be `NR==1` and `FS=;` should be `FS=';'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify delimiter in either BEGIN block or as a command-line option:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"}{ if(NR==1){print $1}}'
awk -F ';' '{ if(NR==1){print $1}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut` might be better suited here, for all lines

```
$ cut -d';' -f1 file
```

to skip the first line

```
$ sed 1d file | cut -d';' -f1
```

to get the first line only

```
$ sed 1q file | cut -d';' -f1
```

however at this point it's better to switch to `awk`

if you have a large file and only interested in the first line, it's better to exit early

```
$ awk -F';' '{print $1; exit}' file
```

Comment: Should be `head -n1 file | cut -d';' -f1`

Comment: yes tnx. didn't notice skipping the first line.  However, reading again, not sure it's actually what OP wants.

Comment: OP's question was "why is `awk` doing this" not "what non-awk ways can I accomplish this same thing"

Comment: Providing alternatives is ok. The SO [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) says: *[...] What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative.*

Comment: Definitely.  OP didn't ask "how do I do [x]" but "when I do [x], why does [y] happen" - yes, TIMTOWTDI, but when you want to know why a specific thing is happening, providing alternatives isn't answering the question.

Comment: @dossy some policing might be beneficial but you need to have to review the question/solutions/comments as a whole.  I explained OPs problem in the comments and provided alternatives.  Still  not clear what the conditions (if any) should be there.  If there are no conditions, alternative solution is a better fit.

Comment: Really not that big of a deal; there are two other answers that do address OP's question of "why" - although not clearly/explicitly.  The "why" is "because you're changing `FS` while processing the first record, so it's only taking effect from the second record onward" - would be good to explicitly state that in whatever answer is accepted.